# How to stream insert JSON array to BigQuery table in Apache Beam

Tags: json, google-bigquery, apache-beam

My apache beam application receives a message in JSON array but insert each row to a BigQuery table. How can I support this usecase in ApacheBeam? Can I split each row and insert it to table one by one?

JSON message example:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "post1", "price": 10},
  {"id": 2, "name": "post2", "price": 20},
  {"id": 3, "name": "post3", "price": 30}
]
```

BigQuery table schema:

```
[
    {
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "INT64"
    },
    {
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "name": "price",
      "type": "INT64"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Yoshei sorry but wasn't sure about the description of the problem. You are asking if you get a JSON array in apache Bean how can you process it and insert row by row to bigQuery. So in your example 3 rows?

Comment: yes as I describe the question

Comment: @Yohei, have you tried https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-a-table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I converted JSON string to List once then c.output one by one. My code in in Scala but you can do the same thing in Java.

```
    case class MyTranscationRecord(id: String, name: String, price: Int)
    case class MyTranscation(recordList: List[MyTranscationRecord])
    class ConvertJSONTextToMyRecord extends DoFn[KafkaRecord[java.lang.Long, String], MyTranscation]() {
      private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[ConvertJSONTextToMyRecord])
      @ProcessElement
      def processElement(c: ProcessContext): Unit = {
        try {
          val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
          val messageText = c.element.getKV.getValue
          val transaction: MyRecord = mapper.readValue(messageText, classOf[MyTranscation])
          logger.info(s"successfully converted to an EPC transaction = $transaction")
          for (record <- transaction.recordList) {
              c.output(record)
          }
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
            val message = e.getLocalizedMessage + e.getStackTrace
            logger.error(message)
        }
      }
    }
```